# Is there a way to use <X11/Xlib.h> and <X11/keysym.h> with MinGW?

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw32

I was surfing the [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org) website and I stumbled upon a 1998 entry named [banks](https://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1998) which is a **Flight Simulator** by Carl Banks. I wanted to try it and so downloaded the files but as you may know (from MinGW) I am on a Windows system,sadly (specifically, Win-7 32-bit) and when I tried to use Cygwin and MinGW to compile the file it showed

```
banks.c:3:16: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
3 | #include       <X11/Xlib.h>
  |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:92: banks] Error 1
```

and the code [banks.c](https://www.ioccc.org/1998/banks.c) included

```
#include                     <math.h>
#include                   <sys/time.h>
#include                   <X11/Xlib.h>
#include                  <X11/keysym.h>
```

Is there a way to compile the file without using Linux?

Comment: Maybe I can save you a bit of time: out of curiosity I tried to build banks.c on a Linux system, and it failed. There's a whole bunch of undefined variables, among other things. I suspect that getting it to build on Windows is only part of the problem.

Comment: @KevinBoone But, the only error I encountered was the above one(while using the [makefile](https://www.ioccc.org/1998/Makefile)) and also no warning whatsoever.

Comment: C (or C++) preprocessor fails at the #include line and the actual compilation does not start at all. This is the reason why you don't see all the errors right away.

Comment: Considering it was a winning entry at IOCCC it should not fail. But if we use the reasoning in answer of @ViktorLatypov I understood why this happened. But I will still try to find how to compile X11 libraries in windows

Comment: Make sure you have installed libx11-devel using the cygwin setup app. This package provides x11/Xlib.h and x11/keysym.h files, among others required to build an X11 client. Compile for cygwin with gcc. This will build the banks x11 client. Also install xorg-server which provide the binaries for the X11 server. And read the docs on https://www.cygwin.com about starting the xserver.

Comment: In C (before C89) there can be default int variables (without explicit type specification), this can explain some bugs in 2020.

Comment: I can confirm this program works (my environment is Ubuntu 20.04, gcc9) - the only things that is important in the Makefile is the "-ansi" switch in CFLAGS. The program compiles with a single (fixable) warning about the unincluded <stdio.h>. The executable runs and acts pretty much like an airplane simulator.

Answer (score 5):

When I wrote it back in 1997, I definitely tested it on Windows using Cygwin, so I know it worked back then, and there should be no reason it wouldn't work now.  In Cygwin's package manager, you'd need to install a package called libx11-dev or something to that effect (the X11 development libraries), as well as an X server (probably called something like Xorg), and of course GCC and the development tools like make.  You should be able to launch a Cygwin X server from the start menu, and in the subsequent terminal window inside the X window, you can cd to the folder where you unpacked the IOCCC winners and run make.  (More detailed information on Cygwin is beyond the scope of this reply; I'm going mostly from memory as I haven't used Cygwin in years.)

But if you want my opinion, don't bother with Cygwin. A much easier way to build and run it would be to just get a Live CD for Linux and boot up Linux directly, and run it there.  Some Live CDs have dev tools like GCC on them, others let you download GCC easily enough.  Knoppix is a common choice.

(If you want to be really kinky, you could try installing Windows Subsystem for Linux so you can run Linux programs natively on Windows.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a Win32 port of X Window server called Xming, it is used rather often for connecting to remote Unix hosts.

If you are using MinGW with MSys2, there is a package called `mingw-w64-libxcb`, so compiling and using X11-based programs can be possible.

Regarding the program itself (banks.c), it is better (though not so straightforward) to compile it for WinAPI directly (yes, I know it sounds harder than simply running make, but the program is rather old and it probably uses non-standard and outdated extensions and peculiarities of the 1998 compilers, so it is better to debug/fix it in a familiar environment, which happens to be Windows in your case). The source code (after de-obfuscation) looks like a graphics program centered around the

```
for ( ; XPending (e) ; )
```

loop, which is directly translated to WinAPI's

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    ... all the code here
}
```

The window creation and key callbacks are also translated to WinAPI.

EDIT1

---

The program works in X11 on Linux out of the box, but it also requires some data to be fed from stdin (that should not be an issue on Windows, but if you do not have "cat" installed, this will also be required).

Comment: Can you please tell how to download `mingw-w64-libxcb`. And when I open msys directory in mingw it shows 1.0 is it version 1?

Comment: I would guess the command to "download" it is "pacman -S <package-name>"

Comment: Ok, so you mean to say that i have to rewrite the whole program to compile it(bcoz that may be hard for me considering my knowledge in this field) or just the above code?

Comment: No, you don't have to rewrite everything. Since Xlib usage is not that extensive, you might spend 15 minutes installing some simple Linux in a virtual machine and compiling the sample with the oldest possible C you can find there.

Answer (score 0):

[X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is a windowing system for Unix-based operating systems, therefore it cannot be used on Windows *natively*.

But there's a way to both run X11 programs and compile them using Cygwin compiler. For that purpose you will have to use [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/), which should contain X11 libraries.

Comment: I installed Cygwin/X through Cygwin but can you please elaborate how to use it to run X11?

Comment: See the documentation on https://www.cygwin.com to start with.